# mysql simple way to transpone rows to columns?

Tags: mysql, pivot, mysql-5.5

i have the following table and need to transpose so that i get an column for each day of month

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/004ff5/4)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE `products_sold` (
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `sold` bigint(41) NOT NULL,
  `outgoing` bigint(32) NOT NULL,
  `incoming` bigint(32) NOT NULL,
  `sellers` int(21) NOT NULL,
  `forecast` float(23,15) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO `products_sold` (`date`, `sold`, `outgoing`, `incoming`, `forecast`, `sellers`)
VALUES
    ('2016-01-01', 1571, 2040, 79827, 3568.738769531250000, 41),
    ('2016-01-01', 7181, 6040, 79827, 3568.738769531250000, 31),
    ('2016-01-03', 4312, 28110, 79827, 3568.738769531250000, 45),
    ('2016-01-04', 3747, 26040, 79827, 3568.738769531250000, 51),
    ('2016-01-05', 5562, 22965, 90523, 2695.571044921875000, 48),
    ('2016-01-06', 6575, 60795, 311421, 3989.669921875000000, 54),
    ('2016-01-07', 5914, 40037, 227773, 3921.460693359375000, 51),
    ('2016-01-08', 9256, 77935, 218118, 3469.458251953125000, 51),
    ('2016-01-09', 5946, 31055, 92081, 2381.977783203125000, 45),
    ('2016-01-10', 4469, 17290, 63145, 1177.376464843750000, 34),
    ('2016-01-11', 4837, 18018, 98986, 3127.859863281250000, 55),
    ('2016-01-12', 7902, 37288, 189488, 3082.014648437500000, 59),
    ('2016-01-13', 8186, 46846, 158957, 3532.484863281250000, 61),
    ('2016-01-14', 7600, 51211, 234417, 3477.270019531250000, 65),
    ('2016-01-15', 8568, 59820, 229810, 3083.817871093750000, 70),
    ('2016-01-16', 6931, 43900, 186547, 2112.100097656250000, 44),
    ('2016-01-17', 5219, 26085, 134130, 967.085449218750000, 42),
    ('2016-01-18', 4997, 31055, 117833, 3568.440429687500000, 49),
    ('2016-01-19', 6787, 61045, 247320, 3499.572265625000000, 60),
    ('2016-01-20', 10875, 56707, 254071, 3992.852050781250000, 76),
    ('2016-01-21', 8782, 57286, 210270, 3926.461669921875000, 70),
    ('2016-01-22', 7215, 46310, 202314, 3476.775878906250000, 75),
    ('2016-01-23', 5167, 26890, 117739, 2390.486816406250000, 49),
    ('2016-01-24', 3729, 33895, 176456, 1176.403686523437500, 40),
    ('2016-01-25', 4249, 32450, 142695, 3491.113769531250000, 59),
    ('2016-01-26', 5529, 33609, 159153, 3374.979492187500000, 58),
    ('2016-01-27', 6328, 33607, 160742, 3969.424072265625000, 56),
    ('2016-01-28', 6961, 36075, 158365, 3892.029052734375000, 61),
    ('2016-01-29', 5792, 37082, 182249, 3426.950683593750000, 65),
    ('2016-01-30', 5490, 28900, 126754, 2328.356933593750000, 41),
    ('2016-01-31', 3933, 23832, 110352, 988.326965332031200, 30);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
 `date`
,`sold`
,`outgoing`
,`incoming`
,`sellers`
,`forecast`
 FROM products_sold
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/004ff5/4/0)**:

```
|                      date |  sold | outgoing | incoming | sellers |  forecast |
|---------------------------|-------|----------|----------|---------|-----------|
| January, 01 2016 00:00:00 |  1571 |     2040 |    79827 |      41 | 3568.7388 |
| January, 01 2016 00:00:00 |  7181 |     6040 |    79827 |      31 | 3568.7388 |
| January, 03 2016 00:00:00 |  4312 |    28110 |    79827 |      45 | 3568.7388 |
| January, 04 2016 00:00:00 |  3747 |    26040 |    79827 |      51 | 3568.7388 |
| January, 05 2016 00:00:00 |  5562 |    22965 |    90523 |      48 |  2695.571 |
| January, 06 2016 00:00:00 |  6575 |    60795 |   311421 |      54 |   3989.67 |
| January, 07 2016 00:00:00 |  5914 |    40037 |   227773 |      51 | 3921.4607 |
| January, 08 2016 00:00:00 |  9256 |    77935 |   218118 |      51 | 3469.4583 |
| January, 09 2016 00:00:00 |  5946 |    31055 |    92081 |      45 | 2381.9778 |
| January, 10 2016 00:00:00 |  4469 |    17290 |    63145 |      34 | 1177.3765 |
| January, 11 2016 00:00:00 |  4837 |    18018 |    98986 |      55 | 3127.8599 |
| January, 12 2016 00:00:00 |  7902 |    37288 |   189488 |      59 | 3082.0146 |
| January, 13 2016 00:00:00 |  8186 |    46846 |   158957 |      61 | 3532.4849 |
| January, 14 2016 00:00:00 |  7600 |    51211 |   234417 |      65 |   3477.27 |
| January, 15 2016 00:00:00 |  8568 |    59820 |   229810 |      70 | 3083.8179 |
| January, 16 2016 00:00:00 |  6931 |    43900 |   186547 |      44 |    2112.1 |
| January, 17 2016 00:00:00 |  5219 |    26085 |   134130 |      42 | 967.08545 |
| January, 18 2016 00:00:00 |  4997 |    31055 |   117833 |      49 | 3568.4404 |
| January, 19 2016 00:00:00 |  6787 |    61045 |   247320 |      60 | 3499.5723 |
| January, 20 2016 00:00:00 | 10875 |    56707 |   254071 |      76 |  3992.852 |
| January, 21 2016 00:00:00 |  8782 |    57286 |   210270 |      70 | 3926.4617 |
| January, 22 2016 00:00:00 |  7215 |    46310 |   202314 |      75 |  3476.776 |
| January, 23 2016 00:00:00 |  5167 |    26890 |   117739 |      49 | 2390.4868 |
| January, 24 2016 00:00:00 |  3729 |    33895 |   176456 |      40 | 1176.4037 |
| January, 25 2016 00:00:00 |  4249 |    32450 |   142695 |      59 | 3491.1138 |
| January, 26 2016 00:00:00 |  5529 |    33609 |   159153 |      58 | 3374.9795 |
| January, 27 2016 00:00:00 |  6328 |    33607 |   160742 |      56 |  3969.424 |
| January, 28 2016 00:00:00 |  6961 |    36075 |   158365 |      61 |  3892.029 |
| January, 29 2016 00:00:00 |  5792 |    37082 |   182249 |      65 | 3426.9507 |
| January, 30 2016 00:00:00 |  5490 |    28900 |   126754 |      41 |  2328.357 |
| January, 31 2016 00:00:00 |  3933 |    23832 |   110352 |      30 | 988.32697 |
```

**But i need to get this**:

```
| date     | 2016-01-01 | 2016-01-02 | ... | 2016-01-30 | 2016-01-31 |
|----------|------------|------------|-----|------------|------------|
| sold     | 1571       | 7181       | ... | 5490       | 3933       |
| outgoing | 2040       | 6040       | ... | 28900      | 23832      |
| incoming | 79827      | 79827      | ... | 126754     | 110352     |
| forecast | 3568.7388  | 3568.7388  | ... | 2328.357   | 988.32697  |
| sellers  | 41         | 31         | ... | 41         | 30         |
```

Is there a more dynamic way than using `CASE`like in this example: [rows to columns mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25942172/rows-to-columns-mysql)

Comment: no. there's no simple way. that's a pivot query, and mysql doesn't support them. the workarounds get extremely ugly, extremely quickly, and can't handle dynamic numbers of row->columns. do the transform in client-side code.

Comment: @MarcB is right. This is a *notorious* pain in the neck in MySQL. It's much easier to get right in client software.  (postgreSQL? MS SQL Server? they have some organized features for this.)

Comment: damn - was afraid that mysql doesn't support stuff like that - so i try to solve in jasper reports - haven't work with it's cross tab function yet - that's why i was hoping there is an simple way ...

THANKS for your fast response guys!